# Any simplest way to get cookie value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I search Google but found entire functions to get cookie value. Isn't there one line statement to retrieve cookie value in javascript?

Comment: This is an oversight in javascript.  Yes, you could use another library to do this for you, but they are in essence implementing the functions you keep seeing.  If you're already using another library, go ahead.  If you are not, you have to weigh downloading an relatively large library (jquery: 31KB, Minified and Gzipped) vs adding less than 1K of js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a javascript library, e.g. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in addition with a plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie

Demo page: http://stilbuero.de/jquery/cookie/

Answer (score 2):

try document.cookie. [Here is a good link](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: That is the link I meant. I don't want to include those functions.

Comment: understood.Any specific reasons?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following one liner to convert your cookie to a map and then access whatever parameter you need.

```
let cookieMap = document.cookie.split(";").map((str)=>str.split("=")).reduce(function(map,curr){map[curr[0]]=curr[1];return map},{})
```

You can checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/59994987/7810354 for an explanation of how this works.

Comment: Some cookies (at least in my browser) are split with `"; "` (note the space). So a better split pattern would be `document.cookie.split(/;\s*/).map...`