# get parameter value from cookie

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a small problem. Currently I have 2 parameters saved in the browser cookie which are ADV and LOC... Now I have a page with a form and the form got two hidden fields :

```
<input type="hidden" name="adv" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="loc" value="" />
```

I need to get the values of adv and loc from the cookie and save them in the hidden form fields... How can i do this please? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any simplest way to get cookie value in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928118/any-simplest-way-to-get-cookie-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.cookie` will get you all the cookies in the following format:

```
'adv=adv_val; loc=loc_val;'
```

To get a value from a cookie, you can use this function (from [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)):

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

To fill in the hidden fields, you can loop though all the hidden fields, and get their respective cookies:

```
function hiddenCookies(){
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
      var element = inputs[i];
      if(element.getAttribute('type') == 'hidden'){
          element.value = readCookie(element.name);
      }
  }
}
```

And then modify `<body>` to have an `onload`.

```
<body onload="hiddenCookies()">
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('input:hidden').each(function(i,v){
      v.value = readCookie(v.name);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks :) then how i cna insert the adv and loc values in the fiels please?

Comment: so this works automatically? If i create a .js file and link it from the page, and then i insert the two hidden fields, it is supposed to work automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet to convert the cookie string into a map.

```
let cookieMap = document.cookie.split(";").map((str)=>str.split("=")).reduce(reduceToMap(map,curr),{});

function reduceToMap(map,currentArray) {
  // convert array to map
  map[currArray[0]] = currentArray[1];
  return map;
}
```

What this is doing is essentially the following:

1. Splitting the string into an array of strings (of the form "key=value")
2. Mapping each string of this array to an array of the form ["key","value"]
3. Reducing this array of arrays (of the form [ ["k1","v1"], ["k2","v2"] ]) into a map

Now you can simply access any cookie by doing the following:

```
let cookieName = "name of the cookie you want to access";
let cookieValue = cookieMap[cookieName];
```