# Javascript equivalent of PHP $_COOKIE["thecookie"]

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any simplest way to get cookie value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928118/any-simplest-way-to-get-cookie-value-in-javascript)

Is there a javascript equivalent to the PHP $_COOKIE["thecookie"] to get the value of a cookie by name? Also, is there a javascript equivalent to the PHP functions isset() or empty() to test the value of the cookie?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few functions for js cookie operations:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

All functions are from [this site](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

Comment: My question was whether the only option was to write one's own function.  This is done so much I thought there might be something out there where people didn't have to continue to have their own functions.